# SAS Enterprise 8.3 oci.dll not found error

Tags: oracle, sas

I am using Windows 10 machine and have Oracle 12.2.0 installed. When I use ODBC, I can connect successfully to Oracle data-warehouses. But when I try to make an Oracle connection within SAS I get the below error

```
615        LIBNAME INFO ORACLE  PATH='XXXXXXXX' SCHEMA='XX' USER='XXXXXX' PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
615      ! ; run;
ERROR: Unable to load oracle client (oci.dll)
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
```

My path variable has the following in it

```
C:\app32\client\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\app\client\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin;
```

I created a system "ORACLE_HOME" variable which its value is

```
C:\app\client\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin
```

Has anyone come across this error and resolved it?

Comment: Where is SAS executing (not EG) - are you connecting to a SAS server, or running in local mode?

Comment: Probably because you have 64-bit SAS and 32-bit Oracle client installed

Comment: @Joe - I am running in local mode. As far as where is SAS executing, my PATH variable contains `C:\Program Files (x86)\Sennheiser\SenncomSDK\;C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\core\sasexe;C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\ets\sasexe;C:\Program Files\SASHome\Secure\ccme4;`

Comment: @Richard - I have both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle installed. They are both in my PATH variable listed in my initial request.

Comment: Put the 64-bit path first in PATH

Comment: @Richard - Thank you. Putting 64-bit path first in PATH ultimately fixed the issue. I also had to remove my testing variable ORACLE_HOME.